# Littlewood Richardson rule and seminormal basis of Specht modules

Tags: symmetric-groups, rt.representation-theory, co.combinatorics

Background

**Seminormal Basis of Specht modules of $\mathfrak{S}_n$**

Let $\lambda$ be a partition of $n$.  A $\lambda$-tableau   is a
bijection $\mathfrak{t}:\lambda \to \{1,2,...,n\}$.  We say a tableau, $\mathfrak{t}$, is standard if the entries are increasing along the rows and columns.   We let $\mathcal{T}_{\lambda}$ denote the set of standard $\lambda$-tableaux.

Given some tableau $\mathfrak{t}$ and two integers $1\leq i < j\leq n$, we
define the axial distance, $a(i,j)$, as follows: if
  $i$ occurs
in row $i_0$ and column $i_1$ and $j$ occurs in row $j_0$ and column
$j_1$, then $a(i,j)=(i_0-i_1) -(j_0-j_1)$.

If $\mathfrak{t}$ is a $\lambda$-tableau and $w \in \Sigma_n$ let
$w\mathfrak{t}$ be the tableau obtained from $\mathfrak{t}$ by replacing each entry
in $\mathfrak{t}$ by its image under $w$.
If $\mathfrak{t}$ is a standard $\lambda$-tableau, we set
$\mathfrak{t}_{i \leftrightarrow i+1}$ equal to $w \mathfrak{t}$
if this is still a standard 
 $\lambda$-tableau, and 0 otherwise.

For a given partition $\lambda$ of $n$, the
Specht   module ${\mathbf{S}(\lambda)}$
has a basis given by the set of standard $\lambda$-tableaux.
With respect to this
basis the generators act as follows
\begin{align*}  
 {\rho_{\lambda}}(s_{i,i+1})\mathfrak{t} = \frac{1}{a(i,i+1)}  \mathfrak{t}  + \left(1 + \frac{1}{a(i,i+1)}\right)  \mathfrak{t}_{i \leftrightarrow i+1}   
\end{align*}

This basis is very compatible with induction and restriction rules (see [*Seminormal representations of Weyl groups and Iwahori-Hecke algebras*, Arun Ram](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9511223)).

**The Littlewood--Richardson rule**

The LR rule describes the coefficients in the restriction 
$$\mathbf{S}(\nu)\downarrow_{\mathfrak{S}_{r_1}\times \mathfrak{S}_{r_2}} \cong \oplus c^{\nu}_{\lambda,\mu} \mathbf{S}(\lambda) \boxtimes \mathbf{S}(\mu)$$

There are many formulations of this rule.  For example, the Jeu de Taquin version maps standard skew-tableaux of shape $\nu/\lambda$ to those of shape $\mu$.  The LR coef, $c^{\nu}_{\lambda, \mu}$ is the cardinality of the fiber $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{t})$ for any $\mu$-tableau $\mathfrak{t}$.

So we have a map from $\nu$-tableaux to $\lambda \times \mu$-tableaux.  The fibers give the LR coefficients.  However, this map is not a homomorphism of Specht modules.

**Question:**

Is there a reference for an explicit construction of such a homomorphism?  I.e. a formulation of the LR rule which is compatible with the seminormal bases of Specht modules.

Answer (score 5):

These references solve the analogous problem for the general linear groups:

- [MR2166314](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2166314) (2006h:20062)  Howe, Roger E. ;  Tan, Eng-Chye ;  Willenbring, Jeb F.
  *A basis for the $\mathrm{GL}_n$ tensor product algebra*,
  Adv. Math.  **196**  (2005),  no. 2, 531–564, doi:[10.1016/j.aim.2004.09.007](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2004.09.007), [arXiv:math/0407468](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407468)
- [MR2888167](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2888167)  Howe, Roger ;  Lee, Soo Teck .
  *Why should the Littlewood-Richardson rule be true?*
  Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)  **49**  (2012),  no. 2, 187–236, doi:[10.1090/S0273-0979-2011-01358-1](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-2011-01358-1)
- [MR0955587](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0955587) (89j:20046)  Tokuyama, Takeshi .
  *Determinantal method and the Littlewood-Richardson rule*,
  J. Algebra  **117**  (1988),  no. 1, 1–18, https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(88)90237-2, ([pdf](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82371588.pdf))

with some work, using Schur-Weyl duality, you should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: @Bruce: Without making any guess about how easy or hard it is to use Schur-Weyl duality here, I'd just add that access to the three papers varies. The first was posted (in at least some version) on the arXiv at front.math.ucdavis.edu/0407.5468, while the AMS Bulletin articles are all freely available online through the AMS webpage. The third paper is older, with access depending entirely on local libraries.

Comment: The third paper is downloadable from http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869388902372 .

Comment: I have added links for all of these, and separate links for the papers in Elsevier journals (though they are available without subscription now)